# How do I translate this 'sparse' Matlab bsxfun call to R?

Tags: r, matlab, vectorization, bsxfun

```
>> A = sparse([1,2,3,4,5])

A =

   (1,1)        1
   (1,2)        2
   (1,3)        3
   (1,4)        4
   (1,5)        5

>> B = sparse([1;2;3;4;5])

B =

   (1,1)        1
   (2,1)        2
   (3,1)        3
   (4,1)        4
   (5,1)        5

>> bsxfun(@times, A, B)

ans =

   (1,1)        1
   (2,1)        2
   (3,1)        3
   (4,1)        4
   (5,1)        5
   (1,2)        2
   (2,2)        4
   (3,2)        6
   (4,2)        8
   (5,2)       10
   (1,3)        3
   (2,3)        6
   (3,3)        9
   (4,3)       12
   (5,3)       15
   (1,4)        4
   (2,4)        8
   (3,4)       12
   (4,4)       16
   (5,4)       20
   (1,5)        5
   (2,5)       10
   (3,5)       15
   (4,5)       20
   (5,5)       25
```

Which looks like this in non-sparse form:

```
>> full(ans)

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     4     6     8    10
     3     6     9    12    15
     4     8    12    16    20
     5    10    15    20    25

>>
```

EDIT:

I would like to do a matrix multiplication of these sparse vectors, and return a sparse array:

```
> class(NRowSums)
[1] "dsparseVector"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"
> class(NColSums)
[1] "dsparseVector"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"
>
```

NRowSums * NColSums (I think; or if that returns a scalar, then flip them) w/o using a non-sparse variable to temporarily store data.

EDIT2:

I currently have this:

```
NSums = tcrossprod(as(NRowSums, "sparseMatrix"), as(NColSums, "sparseMatrix"))
```

This seems a bit awkward for what I'm trying to do, especially the type castings. It's also extremely inneficient, because it computes all elements where either a NRowSum or NColSum exist, and not only the intersection of these two. That is, there are about 100x more entries in this NSums than in the original sparse matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the package "pracma" http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/index.html
Then you can use bsxfun() just as in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do have a "sparse" situation, I think you probably want to start with

```
df <- expand.grid(A=A, B=B)
df$val <- with(df, A*B))
# then pass that triple column set of i,j, and values to the sparse matrix constructors.
```

At the moment your example is not suitable for testing since it is dense.

Comment: The actual data are very sparse. I'll read up on these functions and reply back.

Comment: The problem with this approach (and with my tcrossprod approach) is that it computes values for all pairs of present rows OR'd present columns. When in the sparse array, I only need the present rows AND'd present columns. Significant size increase with the OR (100x). Is there some sort of higher-order mapping function over all entries in a sparse array?

Comment: At this point I challenge you to provide an example to work with. Best to do it in your question body by editing. Your current example is neither R code,  nor is a it a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose your B array to be the same layout as A first:

```
B = t(B)
```

then call the outer product of the two arrays:

```
outer(A,B)
```

Comment: I get a funny output when using arrays. I think you want to use vectors instead: `A <- c(A); outer(A, A)`

Comment: @flodel, you are right, I think it has to do with what outer thinks the dims of the inputs are. For instance, A = c(1,2,3,4,5), outer(A,A) works, but outer(t(A),t(A)) doesn't